# Why won't people respond to their own answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, asking-questions

I asked multiple questions on Stack Overflow and people comment on the questions, but are very vague about it, When I respond back (making sure to @ them) asking if they can give more detail or tell me where to put the code, I never get a response back.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm only seeing two questions of yours on StackOverflow. On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912383/trouble-with-2d-camera-controller-in-unity) both people who provided answers also had somewhat extensive conversations with you in comments/chat. What more are you expecting beyond that? People are busy and they're volunteering their time. They don't always want to sit and have a long back and forth after providing their answers.

Comment: @n8te But if nether answer works then what's the point of any of it?

Comment: They made their attempt to help you. For whatever reason that didn't work. They responded to some of your followup questions. That still didn't work. Time to move on. You win some and you lose some. How long do you figure they're obligated to keep engaging with you?

Comment: @n8te Long enough to get the answer through, we were close to getting it to work. Where do I go from here other than re-post the question? (And have it be flagged as a duplicate)

Comment: Me personally, if I'm real close to getting it to work I'll just keep trying and keep trying on my own until I figure it out. The people who provided their answers helped you get close to a solution....so cross the finish line yourself.

Comment: @n8te I don't know anything about mathf.lerp though

Comment: So read up on mathf.lerp. You don't need people to teach you everything. Learn it yourself. Beyond that I have nothing more to add to this discussion. Good luck.

Answer (score 15):

You're trying to use your [question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851063/how-to-make-a-mario-like-2d-camera-script-in-unity) as a discussion but that's not how these sites work. Your starting point is simply too far away from the answer you need which is why when [each point is solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912383/trouble-with-2d-camera-controller-in-unity) you move onto another problem in the comments.

The fact that your first question was closed as too broad is highly indicative of that.

What you need to do is your own research, spend some time understanding the subject by doing tutorials or reading documentation. Try to solve the issues yourself and thereby understand how to break your problems down into component parts some of which you may solve and others which eventually may make good questions.

One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912574/1038015) does suggest that the "jitter problem" that you'll come across the moment your current problem is fixed is well known and solved in other questions and answers, which you can find by searching on your own.

Eventually the answerers do realise that the amount of hand holding you need is simply not worth it, there are other questions they can answer or other things entirely they need to do so questions that end up requiring a lot of back and forth rarely if ever end well. If it takes more than an hour of back and forth in comments to help you, how many other people could have been helped instead? In the most mercenary terms, [how much rep are you asking them to forgo by doing that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost)? The best you can offer is to accept one answer but you haven't shown any sign to the answerers that that is likely to happen anytime soon with either of your questions.